# Echo text typed to a file

Tags: bash, echo

Usage Example:

```
$ startmem
> command1 
> command2
> command3
> end
$ vi mem.txt

MEM.TXT
-------
command1
command2
command3
```

So basically I need the bash program to echo whats typed into a file, excluding the 'end' statement.

Comment: Could you just do it afterward with, in this case, `history | tail -3 > mem.txt`, though you'd have to know how many commands you wanted that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `cat` with a here document.

```
$ cat <<EOF > mem.txt
command1
command2
command3
EOF
$ cat mem.txt
command1
command2
command3
```